# Xamarin Forms : Bottom TabbedPage not showing badge

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I am using the plugin.badge to add a badge to TabbedPage.
I am placing the toolbar at the bottom by adding

```
xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
            xmlns:plugin="clr-namespace:Plugin.Badge.Abstractions;assembly=Plugin.Badge.Abstractions"
            android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
```

in my tabbedPage xaml.

Everything was working fine with
xamarin.forms 5.0.0.2337 and
xamarin.google.android.material 1.4.0

After updating xamarin.google.android.material  to version >= 1.5
the badge stopped showing.
After some tests i figured out that showing the toolbar at the top by removing
android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom",the badge is showing again.
So it looks like the issue is causing by xamarin.google.android.material version >= 1.5
Is this a known issue or is there something i can do to show the Toolbar at the bottom with  badges ?

Comment: How do you use the `xamarin.google.android.material 1.5.0`? I have  tested on xamarin.forms 5.0.0.2337. The badge shows in the bottom tab.

Comment: Do you have xamarin.google.android.material 1.5.0 installed ?

Comment: I just see that Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2337 requires the version of Xamarin.Google.Android.Material nuget to be '>= 1.4.0.2 && < 1.5.0'.So it seems that i have to wait for an Xamarin.Forms update to use Google.Android.Material >1.5.0

Answer (score 1):

I just see that Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2337 requires the version of Xamarin.Google.Android.Material nuget to be '>= 1.4.0.2 && < 1.5.0'.So it seems that i have to wait for an Xamarin.Forms update to use Google.Android.Material >1.5.0

Comment: If you do not use for this package `Xamarin.Google.Android.Material`, do not install it. The latest version of Xamarin.Forms do not affect the badge.

Comment: I have to use it.I was using 1.3.0.1 .After upgrading xamarin.forms from 5.0.0.2012 to 5.0.0.2337 i got the error Unable to resolve interface type 'Google.Android.Material.Navigation.NavigationBarView/IOnItemSelectedListener'.So i updated Google.Android.Material to 1.5.0 without noticing that Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2337 requires the version of Xamarin.Google.Android.Material nuget to be '>= 1.4.0.2 && < 1.5.0'

Answer (score 1):

Try with `PluginBadge:TabBadge.BadgePosition="PositionCenter"`, it worked for me.