# TabIndicator not displaying with android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom" Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, xamarin

I am working on a Xamarin forms project and in one Tabbed page I need to use tab bar position at bottom. But when I do that the tab bar indicator not working/ not showing. I cannot use **Xamarin community toolkit tabview** either cause there is a bug when you use `NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"` [link](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/issues/625) .

If we remove *android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement*, then tabindictor shows up.

**LifeDueTabbedRM.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
            android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
            x:Class="RSMapp.Views.RM.Life.LifeDueTabbedRM">
</TabbedPage>
```

**LifeDueTabbedRM.xaml.cs**

```
    public partial class LifeDueTabbedRM : TabbedPage
    {
        public LifeDueTabbedRM()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public LifeDueTabbedRM(string c, string u)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Children.Add(new InforceDueView(c, u));
            this.Children.Add(new LapsDueView());

            this.UnselectedTabColor = Color.White;
            this.SelectedTabColor = Color.Blue;
            this.BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#f2b22c");
        }
}
```

**Android project tabbar**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="#05d1f0"
    app:tabIndicatorGravity="top"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="1dp"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="fixed" />
```

Tab bar indicator

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have done a sample to test and the TabIndicator can display at the bottom of the TabbedPage.

According to [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71644970/xamarin-forms-bottom-tabbedpage-not-showing-badge), the problem is the Xamarin.Forms doesn't support the version of Xamarin.Google.Android.Material > 1.5.

What I used:

1. Xamarin Forms 5.0.0.2478 in the share project
2. Xamarin.Google.Android.Material 1.4.0.2 in the android part
3. The code in your TabbedPage.xaml and TabbedPage.cs without the Android project tabbar

**Update**

My Tabbar.xml:

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/abc_primary_text_material_dark"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:tabIndicatorColor="#05d1f0"
app:tabIndicatorGravity="top"
app:tabIndicatorHeight="1dp"
app:tabSelectedTextColor="#008000"
app:tabGravity="fill"
app:tabMode="fixed" />
```

When I deleted the `NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"`, the Tabbar.xml can work in the project, but when I set the `NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"`, the Tabbar.xml will change nothing.

It seems the Tabbar setting in the TabbedPage will cover the Tabbar.xml in the android part.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But still not working for me. I need Tabbar also at the bottom of the screen. When tabbar on the top, the tab indicator showing, but when the tab bar at the bottom of the screen indicator not showing. I also removed the android project tabbar

Comment: But it worked in my project, you can check the updated part in the answer.@D.madushanka

Comment: I got the same result. But where is the tab bar indicator line? I have added a sample image

Comment: I'm sorry for I misunderstood your meaning. Please check the updated part. @D.madushanka